# Regular Expression in preg_split

Tags: php, expression

I dont know what Im doing wrong with this expression:

```
'/^(first part.{1}second part)$/'
```

I would like to split my file by string like this:

"first partZsecond part"

"first partwsecond part"

"first partUsecond part"

and so on.
Thankyou for your help

Comment: There shouldn't be anything wrong with it (assuming you don't have the `'` wrapping your regex), can we see the PHP code? However I suggest you use the regex: `/^first part.second part$/`. Parenthesis aren't necessary and by default, regex matches 1 character so `{1}` isn't necessary.

Comment: my PHP code: $PA_explode = preg_split('/^FINE: Rozpocz.cie paragonu$/', $zawartosc);  $zawartosc looks like: FINE: Rozpoczęcie paragonu\n asdf\n FINE: Rozpoczvcie paragonu\n heasdf\n

Comment: You may want to close and re-ask your question.  The problem lies in the special character `ę`..I'm not an expert with that, but there may be some questions on SO.

Comment: Even if I replace ę with e - it's still a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is with the `\n` symbols. Probably when you're reading those values, each line has the final `\n` included, so it won't match `paragonu$`.

I suggest using `$zawartosc = chop($zawartosc)` prior to using `preg_split()`.

**---- EDIT ----**

```
$parts = explode("\n", $zawartosc);

foreach ($parts as $line) {
  $PA_explode = preg_split('/^FINE: Rozpocz.cie paragonu$/', $zawartosc);
  print_r($PA_explode);
}
```

Comment: with 'chop($zawartosc)' and without '$' at the end of expression still don't work

Comment: Have you assigned the result of the `chop()` method to the same variable? Initially I forgot including the assignation, so it has to be that way: `$zawartosc = chop($zawartosc)`

Comment: I did exactly as you said: $zawartosc = chop($zawartosc);

Comment: PHP fatal error: call to undefined function array_split;

Comment: Sorry, it's `explode()` instead of `array_split()`. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is: `'/first part.*second part/'` its also works with `ę`
Thank you all for your time and assistance